# Angular Material 2 - MatDatePicker Error - 'Must import MatNativeDateModule/MatMomentDateModule'

Tags: angular, datepicker, momentjs, angular-material2

I'm trying to momentjs to format dates in my component controllers where matInput datepicker components are used, but I'm getting the following error in the console when I try to load pages where these are present:

> Error: MatDatepicker: No provider found for DateAdapter. You must import one of the following modules at your application root: MatNativeDateModule, MatMomentDateModule, or provide a custom implementation.

Problem is that I've tried including this in my app module, main app component and child components where I'm trying to reference the `moment()` method, but I still get the error. I've also tried using MatNativeDateModule with the same result.

This is the module dependency that I'm importing:

```
import { MatMomentDateModule } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
```

Datepicker element:

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="invoiceDate" [max]="maxDate" name="date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" formControlName="date">
```

Comment: You're supposed to import it along with the `MatDateModule`. Where are you importing your material date module ?

Comment: MatDateModule doesn't exist...

Comment: MatPickerModule then ? Sorry I don't have all modules in mind, the one you use for the date picker.

Comment: MatDatepickerModule and MatNativeDateModule/MatMomentDateModule are both included in the same import array in the app module

Comment: Could you please make a [mcve] or provide your module code ?

Comment: There is nothing else necessary, given the error message is saying something hasn't been provided that hasn't. Look at the context of the question, don't just slap this on everything that doesn't have blocks of code

Comment: if you're so smart then spot his error. Because without the code of the module, I can't tell if he imported the dependencies correctly, I'm not a psychic. If you are, good, then go ahead. Otherwise, don't bother to comment because you feel offended. I'm here to help him, and for that, I need his code. It's merely a one minute edit, I think he'll be fine.

Comment: It's my post, actually, and I've explained which dependencies have been included, as well as where. I don't feel offended, but like lots on here, you clearly didn't bother to read the full question. If you had, you wouldn't have needed to ask for more code.

Comment: Sorry, I'm author-agnostic. You can say that you provided the required code, for all I care I don't have an issue in my project. If you want to resolve it, then you should listen to me. Because as you can see, another person told you the same thing as I did, because he isn't a psychic either. So either stay with your issue, or comply with the request of someone who is actually trying to help you. It's up to you.

Comment: Nobody else has asked for more code... You've also been told what has been included and where it has been included.

Comment: No, someone said the exact same thing I did, which is import the date picker module. But okay, keep throwing your tantrum, I'm out of here. Good luck with your issue.

Comment: Datepicker module is imported, and there are no other comments asking about this.

Answer (score 34):

Have you added it to your module's imports?

```
import { MatMomentDateModule } from "@angular/material-moment-adapter";

@NgModule({
  /* etc. */
  imports: [ BrowserModule, /* etc. */, MatMomentDateModule, /* etc. */ ],
  /* etc. */
}
```

I've installed it with

```
npm i @angular/material-moment-adapter --save
```

and everything works.

Answer (score 11):

Angullar 8,9

```
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';
```

Angular 7 and below

```
import { MatDatepickerModule, MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material';
```

You need to import both MatDatepickerModule and MatNativeDateModule under imports and add MatDatepickerModule under providers

```
imports: [
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule 
  ],
  providers: [  
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule  
  ],
```

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar error with MatDatepickerModule and MatNativeDateModule which said

> ERROR Error: "MatDatepicker: No provider found for DateAdapter. You must import one of the following modules at your application root: MatNativeDateModule, MatMomentDateModule, or provide a custom implementation."

I solved the issue by doing

```
import { MatDatepickerModule, MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material';
@NgModule({
    imports:[ MatDatepickerModule, 
MatNativeDateModule],
      providers: [MatNativeDateModule, MatDatepickerModule],

})
```

Answer (score 5):

Add

```
import { MatMomentDateModule } from "@angular/material-moment-adapter";
```

and install

```
npm i @angular/material-moment-adapter --save
```

and the dependency also

```
npm i moment --save
```

Answer (score 0):

Just import both below modules in `app.module.ts`

```
import { MatDatepickerModule, MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material';

imports: [   
  MatDatepickerModule,
  MatNativeDateModule
]
```

That's it.